# 14.04 Upgrade warning

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

I currently work on Ubuntu 12.04. When I install Updates though Update manager, it also invites me to upgrade to 14.04. When I accept it, after fetching some packages, it shows a warning[image: screenshot]!

The command `lspci | grep VGA` shows

```
 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: advanced micro devices, inc [AMD/ATI] RV730XT [Radeon HD4670].
```

Should I still go for the upgrade?

Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to believe you are requesting opinions.  My opinion would be that since you are using an LTS version, as am I, you should stick with what works until or unless you are sure you wish to upgrade.  As an LTS version 12.04 is supported for two and a half more years, and I have yet to be convinced there's anything I'll like more about 14.04.  Having said that, I do intend to install 14.04 fresh on another device in order to discover what's new.

On the off-chance you are actually requesting someone take responsibility for the success of your upgrade... I won't be that person.  There's risk in every upgrade, and even the most seasoned veteran will tell you to do a full backup first, at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should still go for the upgrade. You can always switch back to Gnome in case Unity is not properly supported by your graphics hardware.

Here is the bug: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Bugs/UpdateManagerWarningForUnity3D

As it mentions, probably your hardware is outdated so you won't be able to use Unity to its full potential.